# MavensMate Doesn't Bring All the Profile Configurations

Tags: profile, mavensmate, custom-profile

I recently changed few profile names and tried to retrieve them via MavensMate. I noticed that it's missing large number of configurations as the xml code lines reduced from 11,928 to 181. I can see only `<userPermissions></userPermissions>` and `<userLicense></userLicense>` in the new file while the old file is having `<classAccesses />`, `<fieldPermissions />`, etc.

But when I logged into Salesforce I can see all previous classes, pages are still enabled for these profiles which is correct.

Does anyone had this experience with MavensMate or anywhere when you do a profile name change?

Comment: Worth noting: MavensMate is not being updated anymore. Just in case the issue is a result of that, I wanted to post a reminder. Beyond that  you may need to click both `Update Project` AND `Refresh Metadata Index` in MavensMate's control panel, and THEN also refresh the project in Sublime or VS Code or whatever you are using. Redundant? Very. You shouldn't have to do that super often, but I've had a few times where I've had to do all of that to get something to load properly in MM.

Comment: Tried this, no luck

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've set MM to the most current API version in its settings. This doesn't happen automatically each release.

Comment: I assume that you are talking about `MM_API_VERSION`. I updated it to the latest but still it's not updating.